# TestNG: how to know when DataProvider started and ended to call method

Tags: testng

I am using the Data Provider feature of TestNG.
I need something between `BeforeMethod` and `BeforeClass`.

Each item of the `DataProvider` invoke `BeforeMethod` but I want to know when the `DataProvider` starts to send items to method and when it done to do it.

It looks like that `BeforeClass` is too high in the chain.
Is there something in between?

Comment: I do not think there is any hook there.  But, you can probably have your own logic that captures the data.  What is the thing that you are trying to do in these hooks?

Comment: I want to start process before the methods start to run and close it after the Data Provider loop is done.

Comment: when you say dataprovider loop is done, do you mean after the test that depends on the last data provided by the dataprovider has run or right after dataprovider has provided the last data and before the test consuming the last data runs?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the bad wording. I need to know when Data provider start to provide his data and when we provided his last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, There is no such hook.  Workarounds I can think of is if there's something that is passed in the data that tells I am the first one and I am the last one based on which u can start and end your process..or save the size of the data array, increment count on each method run (in beforemethod), check the first and the last count (comparing with size saved earlier) in the beforemethods and perform the required task.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such hook but you can easily insert your own by creating "fake" data providers that invoke your hooks before invoking the real data provider.

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] fakeDp() {
    // invoke before data provider method
    result = invokeRealDataProvider();
    // invoke after data provider method
    return result
}

@Test(dataProvider = "fakeDp") { ... }
```

As for the implementation, you could create your own @BeforeDataProvider annotation and look this up yourself in your fakeDp() and specify this in your test method:

```
@RealDataProvider(dataProvider = "realDp")
@Test(dataProvider = "fakeDp") { ... }
```

Then your fakeDp() only needs to look up the @RealDataProvider annotation to find out which method it should invoke.

Answer (score 0):

BeforeClass does seem like your best option.  You can narrow the scope of your BeforeClass, if you wanted to call the tests in groups.

```
 @BeforeClass(groups = "dataProvider")
 public void dataProviderBeforeMethod() {
   //do something
 }
 @Test(groups = "dataProvider", dataProvider = "dataProviderClass", threadPoolSize = 10)
 public void testWithdataProvider(){
   //test something
 }
 @DataProvider(name = "dataProviderClass", parallel = true)
 private Iterator<Object[]> dataProviderClass() {
   List<Object[]> myData = new ArrayList<>();
     //setup data
   return myData.iterator();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use IDataProviderListener to track DataProvider method start/finish.
Looks like IDataProviderListener does exactly what topic starter needs. IDataProviderListener has two methods beforeDataProviderExecution and afterDataProviderExecution. beforeDataProviderExecution is called when TestNg prepares methods for execution and afterDataProviderExecution is called after all tests prepared to be executed (before any test is started).
Example:

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners(CustomDataProviderListener.class)
public class demo {

    @DataProvider
    public Object[] integerDataProvider() {
        return new Integer[]{1, 2};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "integerDataProvider")
    public void test1(Integer value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}

import org.testng.IDataProviderListener;
import org.testng.IDataProviderMethod;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;

public class CustomDataProviderListener implements IDataProviderListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeDataProviderExecution(IDataProviderMethod iDataProviderMethod, ITestNGMethod iTestNGMethod, ITestContext iTestContext) {
        System.out.println("CustomDataProviderListener -> beforeDataProviderExecution");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterDataProviderExecution(IDataProviderMethod iDataProviderMethod, ITestNGMethod iTestNGMethod, ITestContext iTestContext) {
        System.out.println("CustomDataProviderListener -> afterDataProviderExecution");
    }
}


output:
CustomDataProviderListener -> beforeDataProviderExecution 
CustomDataProviderListener -> afterDataProviderExecution 

1
2
```

Comment: why?please add more details to your anwer